# What does the value 1e100f stand for?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I've seen this in a snippet:

```
animation.repeatCount = 1e100f;
```

my math classes are long time ago. So 1e100f would be a number with 100 zeros? So in this case the programer wanted to have infinite repeatCount?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this page on Timing, Timespaces, and CAAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html), setting the repeatCount to 1e100f "will cause the animation to repeat until it is removed from the layer."

Answer (score 2):

I think its infinity in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) floating point format

Answer (score 0):

0x1e100f is decimal 1970191 - could it be that? Doesn't seem like a round enough number to be deliberate.

EDIT

I just [found the following](https://code.fluendo.com/pigment/trac/wiki/ExistingTimingFrameworks) on Google.. sounds like your answer

```
animation.repeatCount = 1e100f; // this is infinity in IEEE 754 floating point format
```